# Passed by reference in c++ explanation

Tags: c++, pointers, void

I am self studying c++ and I am stuck in the pointers. Particularly in different functions that call the pointers and change them.  I know that for the majority of you here this is very simple but I need some explanation if someone can help me. I am using Xcode on macOS to run c++.

The code that I have is :

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 2, b = 17, c = 1;

void p(int a, int &c) {
    int b = a * c++;
    std::cout <<a <<" "<< b <<" "<< c << std::endl;
    if (4 * a > c) {
        p(b / 2, a);
        std::cout <<a <<" "<< b <<" "<< c << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {

    p(c, a);
    std::cout <<a <<" "<< b <<" "<< c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with output :

```
1 2 3
1 1 2
0 0 2
2 1 2
2 2 3
3 17 1
```

In the beginning it calls `p(a=1,c=2)` where `c` is a pointer. And also the order of actions in `c++` is that first it dereferences `c` and then it increments `c` by one. Therefore `a = 1, b=3 , c = 3`. Why it gives `a = 1, b = 2, c = 3` ?

Comment: `c` is not a pointer, it is a *reference*

Comment: In this code `a * c++` the `*` is multiplication not dereference, there really are no pointers here.

Comment: @John so it goes to global c which is 2 ?

Comment: The variable `c` inside `p()` refers to `a` when it is called by `main()`. Not to the global `c`.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson No, it goes the the local declaration of `c` (which is what shadowing means)

Comment: I suggest you rename the argument variables of the `p` function to something else. Same with the local variable `b`. The more variables are named the same, the more confusing the code will become.

Comment: @John therefore a= 1 and b=1*(2+1)=3.?

Comment: A variable always refers to the most local declaration. This is true whatever the types concerned are.

Comment: Also, please try to avoid global variables. All three of the *global* variables `a`, `b` and `c` could be defined locally inside the `main` function.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson No `a=1` and `b=1*2`. The `++` is a **post increment** operator.

Comment: the `c++` is a postfix increment operator, c is incremented after the line ends .... you should probably learn c++ from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) step by step instead of trying to understand an example made to confuse people by throwing multiple concepts at them at the same time.

Comment: @John ok c++ is the global 1 +1 =2.And why c=3 ?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson In the function the local `c` is a reference to the global `a`. Initially the global `a` was 2, but it has been incremented so it is now 3.

Comment: I also recommend you learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Split up any complex expression into smaller expressions, storing values in temporary variables. And use pen and paper to keep track of the variable values in each call to the `p` function, so you can see their values in each recursive call.

Comment: @AhmedAEK *c is incremented after the line end* This is a confusing way to state the rule. It works in this case but it is not always a correct way to explain how the post increment operator works.

Comment: @John so to get it straight: it calls p(a=c=1, &c=a=2). Then a remains 1,b is a times the increment of global c and c pointer is incremented after all this procedure due to c++? If c++ didn't happened but instead I had b = a*c , the output would have been a=1,b=1,c=2 ?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson No, there seem to be a couple of errors there. Global `c` is not involved at all. There are no pointers. And if your code said `b = a*c;` instead of `b=a*c++;` that does not change the value of `b` at all, the only difference would be to global `a` which would not be incremented. I think you have some fundamental misunderstanding of how variables work, although I'm not really sure what it is.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson A common misunderstanding among beginners is thinking that variables with the same name have some connection between them, so somehow the local `a` is connected to the global `a` etc. This is completely untrue, even when variables have the same name, they are different variables.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson You also might be mixing up pre and post increment. The codes `b=a*++c;` and `b=a*c;` does make a difference to `b`, but `++c` is the pre increment operator and `c++` is the post increment operator, and those work in different ways.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson Final comment, the code you are looking at is needlessly complex and clearly designed to test your understanding. If it is any consolation real code is never this complicated (if it were you would fire the programmer).

Comment: @John thank you for your help.I appreciate it.Is an old exam test that is why the confusing design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the early days of the C language, the only calling convention was *pass by value*. That means that a function only receives a copy of its parameters, and if it changes a parameter, only the local copy is changed and the outer variable still has its initial value when the function returns. So to allow a function to change some variables, we passed *pointers* to those variables, which had to be dereferenced inside the function. Example code:

```
void p(int a, int *c) {
    int b = a * (*c)++;  // outer c variable is increased
    std::cout <<a <<" "<< b <<" "<< *c << std::endl; // this is not C language ;-)
    ...
}
...
p(c, &a);    // explicitely pass a pointer to a
```

Here we *explicitely* pass the address of the outer variable (with `&c`) and still explicitely derefence the pointer inside the function (`*c`).

While being explicit can be fine, it implies cluttering the code with tons of `&` and `*` which is not very beginners friendly...

Then C++ brought *references*. When you pass a variable by reference, the function has no longer a copy of the outer variable but directly uses it. Previous code can become:

```
void p(int a, int &c) {
    int b = a * c++;  // outer c variable is increased thanks to the reference
    std::cout <<a <<" "<< b <<" "<< c << std::endl;
    ...
}
...
p(c, a);    // implicitely pass a reference to a
```

Comment: This is all good, but note that the original code has `p(c, a);` not `p(a, c);` so there is some potential confusion there.

Comment: @john: I had not noticed it... Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer.I appreciate it a lot.Really. But I also have an extra question.Forgive me but I am a newbie in c++.

Comment: 1. Initially p(a= 1 , c = 2) is called and prints a = 1 , b = 1*2 =2 , c = 2+1 =3 (post increment).

2. Enters if 4 * 1 > 3 is true.
      So p(a = 1,c=1) is called and prints a = 1 , b = 1*1 =1 , c = 1+1 =2 (post increment).

3. Enter if 4 * 1 > 2 is true.
     So p(a = 0,c=1) is called and prints a = 0 , b = 0*1 =0 , c = 1+1 =2 (post increment).


4. It enters if 4*0 > 2 is not valid. Then I don't understand where it goes? Does it go back to global variables again?